# WHat are the resources to learn Salesforce Sales CLoud/Service CLoud/Marketing CLoud?

Tags: sales-cloud, service, cloud

Please help me with appropriate resources to learn about Salesforce Service cloud Sales cloud...Are there any work books ?PLease share the link

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs

Answer (score 0):

If you company is a Salesforce partner, there are more training material you can get. As me, I prefer videos more than docs.
Here is the video training page, they have 300+ videos, category by language, product and job role.

https://help.salesforce.com/htsctrainingcatalog